# Show Popup when Location access is disable by user (Andorid Google Maps)

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

how can i show popup which as enable your location access and open Location access intent. right now i am creating app that contain map. i have enabled (map.setMyLocationEnabled(true)). and the app show the current location button but when location access is disable it doesnt show any response.
I want if the location access is disable a popup show which says user to enable the location access

thanks in advance

Comment: just check the location manager of n/w or gps ,if it's get true leave it or else get false show the popup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this code while give you all you want, is any kind of location service available or not ?, Provider, and error message if the is not location manager provider

```
public class LocationManager_check {

    LocationManager locationManager;
    Boolean locationServiceBoolean = false;
    int providerType = 0;
    static AlertDialog alert;

    public LocationManager_check(Context context) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean gpsIsEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        boolean networkIsEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (networkIsEnabled == true && gpsIsEnabled == true) {
            locationServiceBoolean = true;
            providerType = 1;

        } else if (networkIsEnabled != true && gpsIsEnabled == true) {
            locationServiceBoolean = true;
            providerType = 2;

        } else if (networkIsEnabled == true && gpsIsEnabled != true) {
            locationServiceBoolean = true;
            providerType = 1;
        }

    }

    public Boolean isLocationServiceAvailable() {
        return locationServiceBoolean;
    }

    public int getProviderType() {
        return providerType;
    }

    public void createLocationServiceError(final Activity activityObj) {

        // show alert dialog if Internet is not connected
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activityObj);

        builder.setMessage(
                "You need to activate location service to use this feature. Please turn on network or GPS mode in location settings")
                .setTitle("LostyFound")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Settings",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                activityObj.startActivity(intent);
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
        alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

How to use this

```
LocationManager_check locationManagerCheck = new LocationManager_check(
                    this);
            Location location = null;

if(locationManagerCheck .isLocationServiceAvailable){

    if (locationManagerCheck.getProviderType() == 1)
                location = locationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    else if (locationManagerCheck.getProviderType() == 2)
                location = locationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
}else{
    locationManagerCheck .createLocationServiceError(your_activity.this);
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks. Too bad you're using non standard names. `LocationManager_check` ? Why not just `LocationManagerCheck`? `your_activity`? Also, Java has enums. Don't use integers when enums are the perfect fit for your use case.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following statements in onResume:

```
    // Make sure that GPS is enabled on the device
    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean enabled = mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if(!enabled) {
       showDialogGPS();
    }
```

And add the following method in your activity:

```
/**
 * Show a dialog to the user requesting that GPS be enabled
 */
private void showDialogGPS() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setTitle("Enable GPS");
    builder.setMessage("Please enable GPS");
    builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Enable", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            startActivity(
                    new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Ignore", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AlertDialog for popups.

```
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked do some stuff
                }
              })
            .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
```

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-alert-dialog-example/