# Getting the permission to switch on the internet and GPS services

Tags: android

How do i popup a message box that tells the user to switch on their GPS settings. The popup message should also contain a button that would take the user directly to their settings. How can i do it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This also might be a duplicate: [Show Popup when Location access is disable by user](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24160472/2932698)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will leave creation of the dialog / layout / anything else which will display the prompt.

Opening localization settings:

```
 Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(viewIntent);
```

Detecting localization enabled:
[How to check if Location Services are enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311834/how-to-check-if-location-services-are-enabled)